# selecting MINs and MAXs and comparing them

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns id, sellprice, buyprice and date

```
id  sellprice   buyprice    date
1   15      17      2012-6-10 10:21:09
2   18      20      2012-6-10 10:23:34
3   22      24      2012-6-10 10:24:21
4   19      21      2012-6-10 10:25:23
5   17      20      2012-6-10 10:29:34
6   16      19      2012-6-10 10:31:43
7   15      17      2012-6-10 10:34:51
8   16      21      2012-6-10 10:36:13
9   21      23      2012-6-10 10:39:21
```

I would like to choose MIN buyprice and MAX sellprice; and if maximum sellprice price is after minimum buyprice then I want to compare  to get how much I earned - say I bought from **17** then I sold it **22**. As you may see in the table minimum and maximum values may occure several time. How can I query to get the result I want.

The query I am trying has some problem. If I use date to limit in WHERE clause I get "Subquery returns more than 1 row" warning and nothing happens

```
$minmax_query="SELECT 
MAX(sellprice) AS maxprice,
(SELECT id FROM $table WHERE sellprice = max(t2.sellprice)   ) as maxId,

MIN(buyprice) AS minprice,
(SELECT id FROM $table   WHERE buyprice = min(t2.buyprice)    ) as minId
FROM $table   t2 WHERE DATE(date) = '2012-06-10'
```

Comment: Of course it does, you've got multiple smallest prices in there (two times 15).

Comment: How do you know that you bought at `17`? And not at `23`?

Comment: @Boby I know that - MIN and MAX prices may occure several times - Think about this: you buy when the buy price is minimum (cheap) and sell it when it gets high and wait for a while it becomes cheapest again and then you buy it  and then you sell it when it gets higher and so on...

Comment: How do you know it has reached the cheapest? What if you buy and then it goes even cheaper?

Comment: @ypercube, Yes it is impossible to know, this is not something to guess the future; rather it will be about past.

Comment: @ypercube - the confusion is whether these are the regular postings of the price of a single stock, or whether these are the transactions for a given stock... i agree hard to tell. (also - there is no number of shares concept)